# How can I get an array of field from an array of objects that have that field?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array

```
[{price: 65, date: 11-02-2020}, {price: 69, date: 11-02-2020}, {price: 34, date: 11-02-2020}]
```

How could I make an array of prices and an array dates. Without having to use a for or foreach loop?

Comment: What is wrong with using a loop?

Comment: I meant for / foreach loop. Could this be done with array.map() ? Or some function that doesn't obfuscate the code?

Comment: In what way does a for loop obfuscate the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to build an array with specific members :

```js
const datas = [{price: 65, date: '11-02-2020'}, {price: 69, date: '11-02-2020'}, {price: 34, date: '11-02-2020'}];

const prices = datas.map(elem => elem.price);
const dates = datas.map(elem => elem.date);

console.log(prices);
console.log(dates);
```

However, this does 2 loops under the hood. Using a *good old loop* can divide the time complexity by 2 :

```js
const datas = [{price: 65, date: '11-02-2020'}, {price: 69, date: '11-02-2020'}, {price: 34, date: '11-02-2020'}];

const prices = [];
const dates = [];

for (let i = 0, len = datas.length; i < len; i++)
{
  prices.push(datas[i].price);
  dates.push(datas[i].date);
}

console.log(prices);
console.log(dates);
```

Comment: I'd be surprised if the *good old loop* halved the execution time; it wouldn't surprise me if it actually ran *slower*.

Comment: @ScottHunter could be, indeed, we might need some benchmarks

Comment: So "can divide the time complexity by 2" was a bit premature?

Comment: Well, that's a supposition, hence the *"can"* instead of *"will"*

Comment: Except it *can't* since you still do the same number of `push`es.  So, at best, you've eliminated 1/2 of the work done by (at best) half of the code.